# Safe Random String to Program for next Start - C# / VB.Net

Tags: c#

My Program generates a License file with a random Name.
I want to save the random generated String into the Program without creating any external file so the Program is able to find that licensefile at the next Program start.

Is that possible?

Comment: Use a config / settings file from project properties, this is pretty standard in C# and VB.Net

Comment: Yes but that would save a config file in AppData/Local/Appname.. but thank you :)

Comment: Registry? Or on a remote server? It needs to go somewhere

Comment: maybe User Secrets??

Comment: I did not understand exactly, but to store information you have to save it on disk or database or registery. Which registry is right for you